# Identity Server gets caught up during startup

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the prepackaged IDS 5.3.0 as a key manager. When I restart or start the server it always stops for a while on part of start-up, as shown below. I can't really find a solid answer in any of the documentation about it. I never had the older versions do this. I was just curious if I can get rid of this warning.

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuth2ServiceComponent} -  PKCE Support enabled. 
TID: [-1] [] [2017-03-06 14:11:26,275]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
```

Comment: Are you getting this in vanilla pack? Do you run multiple WSO2 servers in the machine or server?

Comment: I downloaded the IDS from this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+with+API+Manager). Then configured it for clustering with another IDS. Both are configured as key manager.

Comment: as @Pubci has asked are you running two IDS in the same machine as it could cause a port conflict unless you change the portOffset

Comment: We run the servers in individual VMs. So AFAIK we shouldn't need to change the port Offset.

Comment: Did that start properly before you cluster?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think I went straight into clustering.

Comment: @BryanMcneil - Did you find a resolution to this? We are encountering the same problem and our IS is taking over 15 minutes to start up!

Comment: Sorry, I never found out the actual problem. I changed some configurations and eventually the warning went away, but regardless it still gets caught up on the PKCE Support. Our server takes about 1 minute to start up, so I feel your issue is a lot bigger. Maybe its related to your actual OS.

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this?